# My kids don't ask to keep my dog, why?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I got Vigilante, the dog, and I brought it home to Hjerim, the Windhelm house and my 2 kids won't ask to keep it. I have no other pets and I have left the house and came back 3 times and they won't ask. Is there a console command? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried reloading one of your previous saves?

Comment: No i havent tried

Comment: Well... what are you waiting for?

Comment: I cant be on my computer all day.

Comment: I think i went inside for a second to see if my second kid was there,xand my other kid had a fox, then i left. This hapend amwhile ago before the glitch

Comment: You might get a better answer over on The [parenting SE.](http://parenting.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem this is a video game, not a real life caring problem!

Comment: @jim http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/339/265/bb8.png

Answer (score 2):

This might be a very big bug for those who want dogs. Try to wait a few days to reset some dialogues, or reload a save. You mentioned your kid has a fox. You can't have a dog to be kept in your house unless they don't have pets. However if you adopted the fox after the bug you encountered, try to download the Unofficial Patch.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in a comment that your children already have a pet fox. This is probably preventing the dialogue asking to keep your dog as a pet. After all, if they have a pet, they aren't desperate to have one. Also, although the descriptions of adopted child interactions suggest that children will always ask to keep your dog, it might be randomly selected from the child interactions available. You might have been unlucky.

Comment: I left before they asked to keep the fox

Answer (score 0):

Try to complete some of the vampire killing quest. My daughter had a fox and then asked to keep the dog. She now has both.